# ordering cards using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html

For an assignment I need to create cards and have the content filled with JS. This I completed no problem. However the next step I need to order these cards. I need to have a button that will set these orders. I have no idea where to start with this. any info would be appreciated!

The HTML. Just used one div to host all of the cards. They show up dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-vK3UTo/8wHbaUn+dTQD0X6dzidqc5l7gczvH+Bnowwk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="logo"></div>
         <ul>
             <li>World</li>
             <li>Sports</li>
             <li>Opinion</li>
             <li><strong>Lifestyle</strong></li>
             <li>Business</li>
             <li>Culture</li>
             <li>Fasion</li>
             <li>Tech</li>
         </ul>
         <span class="icon">
           <i class="ion-ionic" style='color: black; background: black;'></i>
         </span>
     </div>
 </nav>

 <section class="section">
     <div class="container">
         <div style='margin: 40px 10px 40px'>
             <h1>Lifestyle.</h1>
             <p>The latest and best lifestyle articles selected<br/>
                 by our editorial office.
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="cardContainer" id="card-container">

     </div>
 </section>

 <footer class="footer">
     <div class="content has-text-centered">
         <p>
             <strong>Bulma</strong> by <a href="https://jgthms.com">Jeremy Thomas</a>. The source code is licensed
             <a href="http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php">MIT</a>. The website content
             is licensed <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/">CC BY NC SA 4.0</a>.
         </p>
     </div>
 </footer>

 <script type="text/javascript" src='./app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the js below:
The first part is all from the teacher. the list of colors etc. i am using inner html to generate the content.

```
const black = 'rgba(23,35, 50, 1)'
const brown = 'rgba(205,164, 133, 1)'
const greenblue = 'rgba(62,171, 201, 1)'
const pink = 'rgba(254,156, 161, 1)'
const blue = 'rgba(98,189, 254, 1)'


const data = [
    {
        topic: 'Food',
        title: 'Wake Up and Smell the Coffee',
        price: '$0.90',
        color: green,
        overlay: green,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?coffee'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Architecture',
        title: 'The Brand New NASA Office',
        price: '$0.19',
        color: black,
        overlay: black,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?office'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Travel',
        title: 'Experience the Saharan Sands',
        price: '$2.29',
        color: brown,
        overlay: brown,
        img:'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?desert'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Interior',
        title: '9 Air-Cleaning Plants Your Home Needs',
        price: '$0.09',
        color: greenblue,
        overlay: greenblue,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?plants'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Food',
        title: 'One Month Sugar Detox',
        price: '$0.99',
        color: pink,
        overlay: pink,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?sugar'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Photography',
        title: 'Shooting Minimal Instagram Photos',
        price: '$0.29',
        color: blue,
        overlay: blue,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?photography'
    }
]




const cardText = document.querySelector('#card-container')

let html = ""
for (i of data) {
    html = html + `
    <div class="cards" style="background-color:${i.color}; background-image:url(${i.img}); background-size:cover;">
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="background-color:${i.overlay};">${i.topic}</h3>
        <h4 style="background-color:${i.overlay};">${i.title}</h4>
    </div>
    <button>Read for ${i.price}</button>
</div>
    `  
}

cardText.innerHTML = html
```

As I mentioned I need to sort all the cards based on the three different data types above but havent had much experience using sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sort the DOM, sort the data. This way you can sort before the first render of the page.

Create function that take the name of the property you want to sort and the array of data. Just make sure to turn numeric data into numbers!

You can then call this method, changing the property parameter based on button clicked.

```js
const black = 'rgba(23,35, 50, 1)'
const brown = 'rgba(205,164, 133, 1)'
const greenblue = 'rgba(62,171, 201, 1)'
const pink = 'rgba(254,156, 161, 1)'
const blue = 'rgba(98,189, 254, 1)'
const green = 'rgba(0,254, 0, 1)'

/*FUnction to sort the cards*/
function sortCards(property, cards) {
  cards.sort(function(a,b){
    //Return 0 if the same
    if(a[property] == b[property] ) {
      return 0;
    }
    
    //Grab property values
    var a = a[property]; 
    var b = b[property];
    
    //Handle numbers correctly
    if(property == "price") {
      //Make numbers if price - strip $ and ,
      a = parseFloat(a.replace(/\$|,/g, ""));
      b = parseFloat(b.replace(/\$|,/g, ""));
    }
    
    //Normal sort return
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  })
}



const data = [
    {
        topic: 'Food',
        title: 'Wake Up and Smell the Coffee',
        price: '$0.90',
        color: green,
        overlay: green,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?coffee'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Architecture',
        title: 'The Brand New NASA Office',
        price: '$0.19',
        color: black,
        overlay: black,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?office'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Travel',
        title: 'Experience the Saharan Sands',
        price: '$2.29',
        color: brown,
        overlay: brown,
        img:'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?desert'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Interior',
        title: '9 Air-Cleaning Plants Your Home Needs',
        price: '$0.09',
        color: greenblue,
        overlay: greenblue,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?plants'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Food',
        title: 'One Month Sugar Detox',
        price: '$0.99',
        color: pink,
        overlay: pink,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?sugar'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Photography',
        title: 'Shooting Minimal Instagram Photos',
        price: '$0.29',
        color: blue,
        overlay: blue,
        img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?photography'
    }
]




const cardText = document.querySelector('#card-container')

let html = ""

//Sort the data as required
sortCards("price", data) ;

for (i of data) {
    html = html + `
    <div class="cards" style="background-color:${i.color}; background-image:url(${i.img}); background-size:cover;">
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="background-color:${i.overlay};">${i.topic}</h3>
        <h4 style="background-color:${i.overlay};">${i.title}</h4>
    </div>
    <button>Read for ${i.price}</button>
</div>
    `  
}

cardText.innerHTML = html
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="logo"></div>
         <ul>
             <li>World</li>
             <li>Sports</li>
             <li>Opinion</li>
             <li><strong>Lifestyle</strong></li>
             <li>Business</li>
             <li>Culture</li>
             <li>Fasion</li>
             <li>Tech</li>
         </ul>
         <span class="icon">
           <i class="ion-ionic" style='color: black; background: black;'></i>
         </span>
     </div>
 </nav>

 <section class="section">
     <div class="container">
         <div style='margin: 40px 10px 40px'>
             <h1>Lifestyle.</h1>
             <p>The latest and best lifestyle articles selected<br/>
                 by our editorial office.
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="cardContainer" id="card-container">

     </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: whoa! Genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the sort method on your array of card elements

```
yourArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  // a and b are DOM elements from your array!
  let el1 = a.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].value
  let el2 = b.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].value
  return el1 - el2
}
// Wrap your loop and your innerhtml assignment in a function, and now call it again with your new array
```

Docs here show how to write a compare function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Super welcome! I love that idea, sorting DOM elements.